# How can I disintegrate text and rearrange the particles to make a new word in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I have two words: "For" and "By." I need to disintegrate the word "For" so it turns into a bunch of particles. By particles, I mean extremely small circles, similar to dust. Almost like a "Thanos Snap" effect.

Then, the particles need to move around and come together to make the word "By." Then, after a certain amount of time, "By" would disintegrate and form "For." This would continue forever.

I tried making a bunch of individual circles, but I quickly realized that it would be extremely inefficient and I would not be achieve the small particles that I am aiming for. Using HTML/CSS/JS, does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: What in the world are you talking about?

Comment: Similar to how particles are formed in this, [link](https://codepen.io/navin_moorthy/pen/OYVeLw), I need "For" to disintegrate. However, instead of the particles fading away, I want them to come together and create the word "By". Then, the same thing happens but it goes from "By" to "For." This will go on an infinite loop.